# Appropriate datatype for retrieveing a Map field of Arrays from Firestore?

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin, google-cloud-firestore, xamarin.forms

I am trying to retrieve a `Map field` from a Firestore database in a Xamarin.Forms project. The Map field stores 3 `Array` items. The 1st `Array` has elements of type `string` and the 2nd and the 3rd ones have elements of type `number`.

I represent the Firestore documents with `Classes` in my code. I have tried many `datatypes` in order to retrieve the field with no success. Some of them result in getting no data and others result in error.

The last approach I have tried is this:

`public List<(List<string> Item1, List<float> Item2, List<float> Item3)> firestoreField { get; set; }`

It returns an empty `List`.

What would be the correct representation of the above `Map`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what worked:

`public (List<string> Item1, List<float> Item2, List<float> Item3) firestoreField { get; set; }`